# No Handler Registered CQRS-ES

Tags: structuremap, cqrs, event-sourcing

I am creating a cqrs-es test application. I scan command handler against command by following code

```
public class StructureMapCommandHandlerFactory : ICommandHandlerFactory
    {
        public ICommandHandler<T> GetHandler<T>() where T : Command
        {

            var handlers = GetHandlerTypes<T>().ToList();

            var cmdHandler = handlers.Select(handler =>
                (ICommandHandler<T>)ObjectFactory.GetInstance(handler)).FirstOrDefault();

            return cmdHandler;


        }

        private IEnumerable<Type> GetHandlerTypes<T>() where T : Command
        {
            var handlers = typeof(ICommandHandler<>).Assembly.GetExportedTypes()
                .Where(x => x.GetInterfaces()
                    .Any(a => a.IsGenericType && a.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICommandHandler<>)))
                    .Where(h => h.GetInterfaces()
                        .Any(ii => ii.GetGenericArguments()
                            .Any(aa => aa == typeof(T)))).ToList();


            return handlers;
        }

    }
```

I dispatches command as follows:

```
public class CommandBus:ICommandBus
    {
        private readonly ICommandHandlerFactory _commandHandlerFactory;

        public CommandBus(ICommandHandlerFactory commandHandlerFactory)
        {
            _commandHandlerFactory = commandHandlerFactory;
        }

        public void Send<T>(T command) where T : Command
        {
            var handler = _commandHandlerFactory.GetHandler<T>();




            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler.Execute(command);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new UnregisteredDomainCommandException("no handler registered");
            }
        }        
    }
```

When I run the project it throw an exception
"No Handler Registered"

My project location is https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1rU7HOTfLwea0tVOXdIb2Nib2M/edit?usp=sharing

**The Stack-Trace of this exception as follow:**
[UnregisteredDomainCommandException: no handler registered]
   CQRS.Infrastructure.Messaging.CommandBus.Send(T command) in f:\Video\Latest Readable\CQRS Tutorial\CQRS By Authors\HRMSystem\CQRS.Infrastructure\Messaging\CommandBus.cs:31
   HRMSWeb.Facade.DiaryItemFacade.Delete(Guid id) in f:\Video\Latest Readable\CQRS Tutorial\CQRS By Authors\HRMSystem\HRMSWeb\Facade\DiaryItemFacade.cs:59
   HRMSWeb.Controllers.HomeController.Delete(Guid id) in f:\Video\Latest Readable\CQRS Tutorial\CQRS By Authors\HRMSystem\HRMSWeb\Controllers\HomeController.cs:29
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +184
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +211
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass42.b*_41() +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass39.b_*33() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass4f.b_*49() +223
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass37.b_*36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +24
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c*_DisplayClass1d.b_*18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass4.b_*3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c*_DisplayClass8.b_*3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9629708
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on your ObjectFactory.
I don't know if you use some DI container (I can't see your code), but it can't retrieve your handlers.
You should use some kind of Typed Factory, so you could retrieve more than one commandHandler (as you do in your code).

I send you the link of [my training journey into CQRS/ES](https://github.com/williamverdolini/CQRS-ES-Todos): it's very similar to what you're doing and there are some articles about the journey.
I Hope it helps.